# Understanding the syntax of Getters/Setters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Regarding a code example like this one:

```
var someProperty: String = "defaultValue"
    get() = field
    set(value) { field = value }
```

**Is it mandatory to write the get-/set-methods right below the attribute-declaration?** It won't work if I have something in between attribute-declaration and get/set-definition?

**Is the nesting just for better reading or is it part of the syntax?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you're using var and its public all this part

```
  get() = field
  set(value) { field = value }
```

is redundant and the Kotlin compiler should alert about it.

also, you can see that when you compile your code to kotlin byte code **with** or **without** the setter and getter
the outcome is the same

```
@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 4, 1},
   bv = {1, 0, 3},
   k = 1,
   d1 = {"\u0000\u0014\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u000e\n\u0002\b\u0005\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002R\u001a\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004X\u0086\u000e¢\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0005\u0010\u0006\"\u0004\b\u0007\u0010\b¨\u0006\t"},
   d2 = {"Lorg/example/Fo;", "", "()V", "someProperty", "", "getSomeProperty", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "setSomeProperty", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", "stream"}
)
public final class Fo {
   @NotNull
   private String someProperty = "defaultValue";

   @NotNull
   public final String getSomeProperty() {
      return this.someProperty;
   }

   public final void setSomeProperty(@NotNull String var1) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(var1, "<set-?>");
      this.someProperty = var1;
   }
}
```

and last for the order question, The full syntax for declaring a property is

```
var <propertyName>[: <PropertyType>] [= <property_initializer>]
    [<getter>]
    [<setter>]
```

so you cant add anything in between the declaration parts